# Filling in an 8x8 minesweeper grid with mines (Day 2: Diagonal Reverse Synesthesia)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

Note: This is based off of Day 30 of the Minesweeper Advent Calendar on [heptaveegesimal.com](https://heptaveegesimal.com/2018/advent-calendar/bonus-days.php)

So my first minesweeper puzzle did not go so well. I will try to do better today.

First off: This is a torus puzzle. This means that a box, say R1C4 will be affected by mines on R1C3, R1C5, R2C3, R2C4, R2C5, R8C3, R8C4, R8C5 (since this is an 8x8 minesweeper grid) (if this were regular minesweeper)

You might note that each number will have a specific color. Here are the 2 different mechanics for the numbers:

> Number: Tells you how many mines there are on the 4 orthogonal neighbors to a tile (for example, in this puzzle, R1C4 will have the ***orthogonal*** neighbors R1C3, R1C5, R2C4, and R8C4)

> Color: You'll have to deduce this yourself, however a hint: A red 3 would indicate that there are 3 mines on the diagonal tiles and all orthogonal tiles are safe.

Mines used in this puzzle: Single (1), anti-mine (-1)

No numbers are missing. No mines aren't accounted for.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\color{red}{-1}$ |  |  | $\color{green}{4}$ |  |  |  | $\color{green}{-3}$ |
| $\color{red}{-3}$ | $\color{green}{-2}$ | $\color{green}{0}$ |  | $\color{blue}{7}$ |  | $\color{green}{-2}$ |  |
| $\color{green}{-3}$ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | $\color{green}{0}$ |  | $\color{blue}{6}$ |  | $\color{red}{0}$ |  |
|  | $\color{green}{0}$ |  |  |  |  | $\color{red}{-2}$ |  |
| $\color{green}{-1}$ |  | $\color{blue}{2}$ |  | $\color{blue}{5}$ |  | $\color{green}{3}$ |  |
|  | $\color{green}{0}$ |  |  |  | $\color{blue}{-3}$ |  | $\color{green}{-2}$ |
| $\color{green}{1}$ |  | $\color{green}{2}$ |  |  | $\color{green}{-1}$ |  |  |

<sub>why do I feel like the number in R2C1 will be the net vote count after I wake up tomorrow?</sub>

<sub>also technically it's already time for a day 2 because SE counts days in UTC (it's 1:50AM there)</sub>

Comment: I think the red -4 on the left contradicts the hint about the colours, it has to have a -1 on an orthogonal cell at R2C8

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh right right, I'll fix the number when I wake up tomorrow

Comment: Don’t worry if your puzzles don’t always go well @CrSb0001– they’re still very interesting and definitely appreciated!

Comment: @Bryce lol I know :)

Comment: Also sorry about the hints about the numbers/colors not making a whole lot of sense, I just paraphrased them from the instructions for Day 30 of the Minesweeper Advent Calendar that I got inspiration for this from, and couldn't make it make more sense.

Comment: If numbers count mines on the _orthogonal_ tiles, how can a red 3 mean all orthogonal tiles are safe?

Comment: @Someone I misworded that a bit, unsure how to fix it. I think what I was trying to say is that a number represents that there are mines on the tiles that are affected by the color (if that even makes sense)

Comment: I think that makes more sense.